# Setting DatePicker not working?

Tags: java, android, android-datepicker

I am trying to set my DatePicker to the current date in the OnCreate method of my activity:

```
    DatePicker dp = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    dp.updateDate(year, month, day);
```

However this does not seem to change it?

Comment: do you want to set the date from a date picker dialog or want add the datepicker widget in layout xml..? datepicker widget is something like calendar ... if you want show a datepicker dialog and set the date, then Kat-hat's answer will help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let you all know, that code actually works fine my problem was that the date of my device was wrong! Sorry about that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

DatePickerDialog datedialog = new DatePickerDialog(Activity.this, mDateSetListener, year, month, day);
datedialog.show();
```